# Check for specific string format

Tags: java, string

How would I check in java if a string entered match the required format of `aa/dddd` where `a` represents a lower or upper-case letter and `d` represents a number

Comment: Have you tried `matches` method from String? It would require little regex knowledge so if you don't know regex you can also try with `charAt(index)` and `Character.isLowerCase` or `Character.isDigit` methods.

Comment: This is a perfect use-case for regular expressions! I do not have an answer right now, but you should definitely look into that. The `matches` method uses regular expressions. Edit: I was too late, @mishadoff already got it :)

Answer (score 3):

A simple regex to use: ^[A-Za-z]{2}/[0-9]{4}$

```
String regex = "^[A-Za-z]{2}/[0-9]{4}$";

String test = "ab/1232";
if (test.matches(regex)) {
    // my regex matches
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe

```
String.matches("[A-Za-z]{2}/\\d{4}")
```

or

```
String.matches("[A-Za-z]{2}/[0-9]{4}")
```

would work.

Comment: `matches` takes String as argument. You forgot to surround regex with `"` and escape ``\``.

Comment: Thanks. Writing regex is always an iterative process for me...

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
String str="aF/1234";

if(str.matches("[a-zA-Z]{2}/\\d{4}"))
    System.out.println("Match");
```